Flatting out multiple nested dictionary into a dataframe for use in data modeling
I am slowly working through different python courses to teach myself Python. After taking courses for ~ a month I started to work on building a model using a data API feed from DataGolf.
The data is golf information from PGA tour events for the calendar year 2023, by event, and includes scoring statistics for every round.
After flattening out the file I used pandas to put it into a DF the column headers were the event and one of the rows 'scores' had a nested dictionary.
Dataframe
The data looks like this
{'10': {'event_completed': '2023-02-26',
'event_id': '10',
'event_name': 'The Honda Classic',
'scores': \[{'dg_id': 12423,
'fin_text': '1',
'player_name': 'Kirk, Chris',
'round_1': {'course_name': 'PGA National Resort (The Champion)',
'course_num': 734,
'course_par': 70,
'driving_acc': 0.571,
'driving_dist': 281.3,
'gir': 0.667,
'great_shots': 2,
'poor_shots': 3,
'prox_fw': 28.944,
'prox_rgh': 23.543,
'score': 69,
'scrambling': 0.714,
'sg_app': 1.704,
'sg_arg': 1.206,
'sg_ott': 0.965,
'sg_putt': -1.806,
'sg_t2g': 3.875,
'sg_total': 2.069,
'start_hole': 10,
'teetime': '12:29pm'},
'round_2': {'course_name': 'PGA National Resort (The Champion)',
...
...
'round_3': {'course_name': 'PGA National Resort (The Champion)',
...
{'dg_id': 21756,
'fin_text': '2',
'player_name': 'Cole, Eric',
'round_1': {'course_name': 'PGA National Resort (The Champion)',

I was able to figure a way to take the data and break out the event by event ID and scores. However, this only allows me to do it to each event.
Second Table by event
This led to a nested list for each round that includes scoring information by golfer.
Lastly, I was able to take the last table and the nested dictionaries and create the following
Broken out by event, player, and scoring in each round
I want to do this for each event for the years 2016-2023 and build it into a DF that I can use to build models for golf prediction.
I used the following lines of code to import different packages
pip install flatten_json
from flatten_json import flatten
import pandas as pd
import requests
import ast
import numpy as np
golf_api = 'https://feeds.datagolf.com/historical-raw-data/rounds?tour=pga&event_id=all&year=2023&file_format=json&key=xx'
r = requests.get(golf_api)
data = r.json()
dfgolf1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

dfgolf1
entries = data['3']['scores']
dfgolf2 = pd.DataFrame(entries)

dfgolf2
After looking at stackoverflow, pandas, and other resources I tried the following and was able to break out the table in a formation I could use in a model. But it is still not ideal.
df = pd.json_normalize(entries, sep='_')
df

df
All of this allowed me to get the data into a dataframe I could use to model. But I would need to repeat the process over and over. That is what I wanted to avoid. I was trying to find a way to loop entries = data['3']['scores'], however, I kept getting errors using different suggestions from stack overflow.
Can anyone help me find a more efficient way?
My plan is to take this data, store it into a SQL DB and continue to progress into the next steps. In the end, I want to use this as a portfolio project. Thank you to anyone who can help. Or can even point some links to another post that is similar. I am still reading about dictionaries with nested dictionaries, with a dictionary in a list I think. I see the brackets as
{event_ID:{event_completed:...[{dg_id':
So I think that is a dictionary, with a nested dictionary, with a nested dictionary in a list?
